# Could the moon move balls on perfectly flat and level surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, moon, tidal-effect

I've been looking into the concepts of highly flat surfaces and highly round objects, and I'm wondering if an experiment like this would work / has been done:

- Take a perfectly flat surface
- Level it
- Put a highly round ball on it
- See if it is moved by the gravity of the moon passing overhead

In theory it should work, in practice the question would come down to friction.

Has an experiment like this been attempted? What would prevent this kind of experiment from working?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/49870/234182

Comment: And this: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/11616

Answer (score 3):

Your intuition is correct: tidal forces would cause the ball to move.  A slightly simpler experiment to analyze would be a ball on a perfectly spherical, smooth Earth.  Just as the rotation of the earth under the moon and sun causes traveling bulges that follow the apparent positions of the moon and sun, the ball would tend to follow the sun or moon.

Comment: The gravitational force in question isn't a tidal force.

Comment: @lsusr: *The gravitational force in question isn't a tidal force.* Actually it is. The effect of the straight Newtonian gravitational force vanishes to first order because the earth is also subject to it.

Comment: McGrew is correct. Thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 0):

In principle, yes.

In practice, no. The real Earth is sufficiently flexible over its large size that it deforms in response the the tidal forces. If this was perfect, Earth’s surface would move so as to always be “flat”, so there’s no tilt to move the ball.

It’s not quite perfect, Earth resists a bit, but the defect is only roughly 1m of height along 10000km of a quarter-circumference of the Earth. This is a *tiny* tilt, 0.1 micron per meter.